# Center absolute div indside/outside relative div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, positioning

Is it possible with either CSS or jQuery to center an absolute div inside or outside a relative div, if you dont know the width of the relative div witch in this case is the parent element of the two.

normally i would do something like:

```
.child {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: -50px;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
}
```

but only if i knew that the parent is 100px wide, but what if i dont know?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gmmqh/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to target IE8 and lower, you can use the CSS3 `calc()` function:

`left: calc(50% - 100px);`

Replace 100px with half of whatever width your *absolute positioned child element* is.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gmmqh/5/

Note the use of `box-sizing: border-box` to make the boxes even with each other, like on the third one.

Comment: i know, but i dont know the size of the parent element should centered  to.

Comment: You don't need to know the size of the parent. You just need to know the size of the *absolutely positioned child element* and divide it by half.

Answer (score -2):

To center anything use below code

```
margin:0px auto;
```

So your .child becomes

```
.child {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    /*left: -50%;*/
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #eee;
    border: solid 3px #ddd;
}
```

Comment: This does not work on absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: OOPS, I am sorry was not aware of that. Thanks.